# What are the practical uses of resx file?

Tags: asp.net, resx

What are the practical uses of resx file?

I am using .net 1.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store resources:

- Images
- Strings
- Embedded Files
- .... and more

[Resources in .Resx File Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ekyft91f(VS.71).aspx)